# How can I change the color of certain characters in a TRichEdit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, trichedit

I'm doing a Delphi 7 project where I have to let a user enter in a number (Layers going down) to build a Christmas tree, but I also need to display the output as `*` (stars). I am having a problem editing a certain line of stars in the TRichEdit to make the color change randomly just like a real Christmas tree shines.

Comment: Why bother using a RichEdit to make a "blinking christmas tree" when you could do it much more easily in a `TPaintBox`?

Answer (score 4):

Formatting in rich edit controls works by first selecting text, then applying formatting to that selection.

Select the text with the [`SelStart`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.SelStart) and [`SelLength`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.SelLength) properties.

Apply formatting with the [`SelAttributes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.SelAttributes) property, for example `SelAttributes.Color := clRed;`.

Comment: How would you use it like this redout.selstart := 2;

Comment: SelStart refers to the character index rather than the line. Otherwise it would be impossible to format characters within a paragraph.

Comment: How do you use the select Property does it select a line or a character

Comment: Um how do you make a range for the Selstart to select

Comment: I don't understand that question. Be precise. Also, read the vcl help for the properies I directed you towards.

Comment: SelStart := 0; SelLength := 1; SelAttributes.Color := clRed; makes the first character red

Comment: @David - +1, but I'm not 100% sure if the [SelAttributes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.SelAttributes) were already introduced in Delphi 7.

Comment: @daemon_x In fact it was introduced long before D7. I think that without these properties, `TRichEdit` would be essentially useless and so I bet it was there from version 1.

Comment: @David - that's right, maybe I missed them, because I remember I've been using directly [EM_SETCHARFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774230%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).