# How do you change the color of specific characters in a rich edit in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, character, richedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the color of certain characters in a TRichEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978850/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-certain-characters-in-a-trichedit)

I have to do a project in which I have to either change the color of specific individual characters in a line in a rich edit to random colors or change the color of a whole line in a rich edit to random colors . 
Is it possible to keep randomly changing the color of a string or character which appears in the rich edit and how ?
The colors have to keep flickering too to give a constant blinking effect like lights flashing on and off in the rich edit . Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Same homework? - [(How can I change the color of certain characters in a TRichEdit?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978850/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change all the attributes of selected portions of text in a RichEdit (font, size, color, style) whenever you want at runtime by selecting that area (with SelStart and SelLength) and changing the attributes (with SelAttributes).